# Its necessary to remove comments from strings.xml file on Android?

Tags: android, xml, security, mobile, apktool

for security reasons is necessary remove all mi sensitive comments like `urls`, so i wonder if is necessary to remove it from my `strings.xml` file, because I researched and I found when application is package into `*.apk` the comments inside of an `layout.xml`  will be suppressed, but i can't figured out if it apply too for the comments in the path `res/values/*.xml`

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to remove the comments from any xml resources. They are removed automatically when you compile the apk file.